# Variable getting the wrong value?

Tags: c

Hello guys I need to make a program in which you input a number n.
 It's not specified how large is n going to be so theres no limit.

The output is supposed to be: example `n = 123456`

1. `123456 - 12345 + 1234 - 123 + 12 - 1 = 112233`
2. `1 + 12 + 123 + 1234 + 12345 + 123456 = 137171`

I have the first part done, and the second as well but when I am printing the second equation it printing values that are not what I calculated.

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int num,sum,num2=0,sum2=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,base;
    int a=0;
    printf("Enter an integer >=0: ");
    scanf("%ld",&num);
    c=num;
    sum=num;
    printf("%ld ",num);
    while(num>0)
    {
        if(a==0)
        {
            num/=10;
            sum-=num;
            printf(" - %ld",num);
            a=1;
        }
        else if (a==1)
        {
            num/=10;
            sum+=num;
            printf(" + %ld",num);
            a=0;
        }
    }
    printf("= %ld\n",sum);
    d=c;
    printf("d: %ld\n ",d);
    while(d>10)
    {
        b++;
        d/=10;
        printf("%ld\n",d);
    }
    printf("b:%lu\n",b);
    printf("c: %lu\n",c);

    for(b;b>0;b--)
    {
        base=10^b;
        num2=c/base;

        if (b==1)
        {
            printf("%ld",num2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%ld + ",num2);
        }
        sum2+=num2;
    }
    printf("= %ld",sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I have extra values and that I'm printing others that are not what I state as needed, I'm just checking what values are incorrect. I think I'm getting the wrong values for `num2=c/base;` because of how I'm printing it or because of the variable type, I'm trying with the number 5005005, `num2` the first time should be 5 and I am getting 417k ish. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I changed the power error, but now the program is crashing.

new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int num,sum,num2=0,sum2=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,base;
    int a=0;
    printf("Enter an integer >=0: ");
    scanf("%ld",&num);
    c=num;
    sum=num;
    printf("%ld ",num);
    while(num>0){

            if(a==0){
            num/=10;
            sum-=num;
            printf(" - %ld",num);
            a=1;
            } else if (a==1){
            num/=10;
            sum+=num;
            printf(" + %ld",num);
            a=0;
            }

    }
    printf("= %ld\n",sum);
    d=c;
    printf("d: %ld\n ",d);
    while(d>10){
        b++;
        d/=10;
        printf("%ld\n",d);
    }
    printf("b:%lu\n",b);
    printf("c: %lu\n",c);



    for(b;b>=0;b--){
        base= powl(10,b);
        num2=c/base;

        if (b==0){
            printf("%ld",num2);
        }else{
        printf("%ld + ",num2);
        }
        sum2+=num2;
        printf("%ld",sum2);
    }
    printf("= %ld",sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

edit2: fixed it, I still don't know why it crashes when using >=0

here's the fix:

```
for(b;b>0;b--){
            base= powl(10,b);
            num2=c/base;

            if (b==1){
                printf("%ld + ",num2);
                sum2+=num2;
                num2=c;
                printf("%ld",num2);
            }else{
            printf("%ld + ",num2);
            }
            sum2+=num2;
            printf("%ld",sum2);
        }
```

Comment: `10^b` is "10 xor b", not "10 multiplied b times".

Comment: Since `b` is **unsigned** number, `b>=0` will never be false.

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot calculate power via `^` operator: it is xor operator.
- `d>10` will lead to wrong result when the top two digit of input is `10`.
- Inclemented `b` because the last number lacked.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int num,sum,num2=0,sum2=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
    int a=0;
    printf("Enter an integer >=0: ");
    scanf("%ld",&num);
    c=num;
    sum=num;
    printf("%ld ",num);
    while(num>0){

        if(a==0){
            num/=10;
            sum-=num;
            printf(" - %ld",num);
            a=1;
        } else if (a==1){
            num/=10;
            sum+=num;
            printf(" + %ld",num);
            a=0;
        }

    }
    printf("= %ld\n",sum);
    d=c;
    printf("d: %ld\n ",d);
    while(d>=10){
        b++;
        d/=10;
        printf("%ld\n",d);
    }
    printf("b:%lu\n",b);
    printf("c: %lu\n",c);


    for(num2=c,b++;b>0;b--){

        if (b==1){
            printf("%ld",num2);
        }else{
            printf("%ld + ",num2);
        }
        sum2+=num2;
        num2/=10;

    }
    printf("= %ld",sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To get `1 + 12 + 123 + 1234 + 12345 + 123456`,
you can use `base` to calculate the numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int num,sum,num2=0,sum2=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,base=1;
    int a=0;
    printf("Enter an integer >=0: ");
    scanf("%ld",&num);
    c=num;
    sum=num;
    printf("%ld ",num);
    while(num>0){

        if(a==0){
            num/=10;
            sum-=num;
            printf(" - %ld",num);
            a=1;
        } else if (a==1){
            num/=10;
            sum+=num;
            printf(" + %ld",num);
            a=0;
        }

    }
    printf("= %ld\n",sum);
    d=c;
    printf("d: %ld\n ",d);
    while(d>=10){
        b++;
        d/=10;
        base*=10;
        printf("%ld\n",d);
    }
    printf("b:%lu\n",b);
    printf("c: %lu\n",c);


    for(b++;b>0;b--){

        num2=c/base;
        if (b==1){
            printf("%ld",num2);
        }else{
            printf("%ld + ",num2);
        }
        sum2+=num2;
        base/=10;

    }
    printf("= %ld",sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this still helped, that fix gives me 123456 + 12345 + 1234 + 123 + 12 + 1, I needed 1 + 12 + 123 + 1234 + 12345 +123456. Thanks still.